# Zend application on pagodabox shows error?

Tags: zend-framework, frameworks

I am using Zend framework previously my application was working fine.
When I shifted it to pagoda box it gives me this weird error

[App link](http://stores.rocxial.com/public/Index)

If anyone have face this issue .........and zend works fine on Pagoda box or not?

Comment: I thinks it's time you explored the documentation of Pagoda... start here http://help.pagodabox.com/customer/portal/articles/175452-zend-framework

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to add a file named **Boxfile** to the project folder (but not the */public* one).

A minimal content of **Boxfile** needed to run ZendFramework *Hello World* application is:

```
web1:
    document_root: public
```

where `web1` is the instance name.

Also you should have a general ZF `.htaccess` in your application */public* folder:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```